# How to replace a word in a loop [Dart]

Tags: loops, dart

So this is the famous song of the 99 beers so, the goal here is to figure out how to print the sentence in a loop. The problem is, when I need to print in singular (1/0 bottle of beer), I don't know how to do the logic-replacement (I am a newb).

```
var text = '99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer. Take one down and pass it around, 98 bottles of beer on the wall.';

void main() {
  for (int i = 99; i > 0; i--) {
      print('$i bottles of beer on the wall, $i bottles of beer. Take one down and pass it around, ${i-1} bottles of beer on the wall.');
  } 
}
```

I know this is so basic-simply but I got stuck ^^'...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'$i bottle${i>1 ? 's' : ''} of beer on the wall, ....'
```

Comment: Thank you. The ternary Op is good. However, in the last sentence doesn't work cause of the ${i-1}. You'll get this: _2 bottles of beer on the wall, 2 bottles of beer. Take one down and pass it around, **1 bottles** of beer on the wall._

Comment: Dude, you should change the test, example: `i-1 > 1`.

Comment: Thanks man. I am starting knowing how logic works through the methods of the language. My way was using "replaceAll()"  but ternary was the simplest thing.